# python complete, file vs object

Tags: python, python-2.x, readline, pythoninterpreter

I recently discovered auto-completetion in the python interperter here: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/interactive.html .
This is fantastic for speeding up tests that I do in the interactive interpreter.  There are two things that complete does that are both useful.

If I simply put `C+f: complete` in my .inputrc (or use readline without rlcompleter), when I press Ctl+f, I get completion of files in the directory that I started the interpreter from.  When I load the modules `readline` and `rlcompleter` and add `readline.parse_and_bind('C-n: complete')` to the .pystartup file, it converts both the Ctl+n and Ctl+f to auto completing python objects.

I would like to do both, but am not sure how to keep `rlcompleter` from overriding the standard complete.  Is there a way to start up two instances of `readline`, one that does and one that doesn't use `rlcompleter`?

Here is my .pystartup file

```
import atexit
import os
import readline
import rlcompleter #removing this does file completion.

readline.parse_and_bind('C-n: complete')

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```

Answer (score 0):

How it works:

When you import `rlcompleter`, it install `rlcompleter.Completer().complete` as `readline`'s completer: `readline.set_completer(Completer().complete)`.

Without `rlcompleter`, `completer` is `None`, so the underlying GNU readline lib use `rl_filename_completion_function` by default.

Binding key and completion logics are implemented by GNU readline lib so there is nothing to do in Python about `start up two instances of readline`...

---

I don't find a way to call default `rl_filename_completion_function` in Python(It is possible in C extension), so I guess you have to duplicate the logic of `rl_filename_completion_function` in Python.

Which means you should inherit `Completer` and build your custom `complete`. But you still cannot split these two logics to `C-n` and `C-f` :(

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I wonder if there is a way to write a function to                                          unload rcompleter when the right keys are pressed, then reload it...